Nuxt 3 SSR: Strapi fetch in useAsyncData is called client-side
Setup
Nuxt 13.14.159
nuxtjs/strapi 1.12.0
Expected behavior
In my Nuxt 3 application, I have a dynamic page pages/articles/[slug].vue which I want to be rendered server-side every hour. The content for this dynamic page is fetched from a Strapi 4 CMS. When a user navigates to this page (for example /article/abc), I want the server to respond with the pre-rendered page, without fetching the content client-side. The same behavior is expected, when a user navigates to the page directly by its full url.
Current behavior
When I navigate to the page /article/abc via <NuxtLink> I can see a fetch in the browsers network tab https://api-domain/articles?filters[slug]=abc which is not expected. If I enter the page directly by its full url, the content isn't fetched from the CMS client-side.
Code
/pages/articles/[slug].vue
<script setup>
  const route = useRoute();
  const { find } = useStrapi4();

  const slug = route.params.slug;
  const { data } = await useAsyncData(
      slug,
      async () => {
        const response = await find(
            "articles",
            {
              filters: {slug: slug}
            });

        return response.data
      }
  );

 ...
</script>


nuxt.config.ts
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  modules: [
    "@nuxtjs/strapi",
  ],
  routeRules: {
    "/": { prerender: true },
    "/articles/**": { swr: 3600 },
  },
  strapi: {
    url: <strapi url>
    prefix: "api",
    version: "v4",
  },
});

How to achieve the expected behavior?

I believe that is intentional. For SSR, only when you directly navigate to a page will it get "server-side rendered". The benefit being you don't need loading screens beyond the initial one and the server makes the API call instead. This helps with SEO since it doesn't need JS to read your site. However, once the Nuxt app is already loaded, you only need to update the changes. Therefore every subsequent navigation via NuxtLink will only get the data requested by that page. Hence why it makes the API call from the client instead. How were you expecting it to work?

Thanks @MagnieMozios. I agree with you when saying: on a subsequent navigation via <NuxtLink> the app only requests the data it needs. But, in a server-side rendering mode, I expect the data related to that page are fetched during the server-side rendering process and then stored in the payload. According to the docs, that is a common use case for the useAsyncData function. Hence, the data the client needs for the page, should be found in the payload and not be requested from the API again.

Solution
After spending a while trying to understand the question, the intended behavior, researching and writing an answer, I think the solution is to change your /articles page to a "Server-Only Page":

You can define a page as server only by giving it a .server.vue suffix. While you will be able to navigate to the page using client-side navigation, controlled by vue-router, it will be rendered with a server component automatically, meaning the code required to render the page will not be in your client-side bundle. -- https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/pages#server-only-pages

You can do that by renaming pages/articles/[slug].vue to [slug].server.vue. This means it will never be rendered client-side, meaning useAsyncData() will never be used on the client and solving your issue with the client calling the API.
Explanation/clarification of why it doesn't work in the expected way...

I have a dynamic page pages/articles/[slug].vue which I want to be rendered server-side every hour.

Server-side rendering only happens on initial page load. When someone hits the server for the initial page load, it can then cache that information for an hour after which point the cache expires and the next time a person does an initial page load will the cache refresh. However, after that point everything is done via the client:

Once the HTML document has been downloaded, the browser interprets this and Vue.js takes control of the document. The same JavaScript code that once ran on the server runs on the client (browser) again in the background now enabling interactivity (hence Universal rendering) by binding its listeners to the HTML. This is called Hydration. When hydration is complete, the page can enjoy benefits such as dynamic interfaces and page transitions.
-- https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/rendering (emphasis mine)

useAsyncData() is just a tool to make it possible to get API data on the server while also making it possible to get the data from via the client (browser).

It returns reactive composables and handles adding responses to the Nuxt payload so they can be passed from server to client without re-fetching the data on client side when the page hydrates. -- https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-async-data

This means that on initial page load the server calls the API endpoint. However, only the "payload" from that initial call is passed to the client. So if your initial view is /articles/abc then the server calls https://api-domain/articles?filters[slug]=abc. But if you then go from /articles/abc to /articles/xyz, then client does not have the data from https://api-domain/articles?filters[slug]=xyz which is why the client makes the call. Which is exactly what is happens as you've explained and experienced in your question and why I said "I believe that is intentional."
Another possible solution...
Before I realized that "Server-Only Pages" was a thing, my workaround was that you could use the prerender:routes hook to get a list of all available pages and then rebuild your site every hour.. but that only makes sense if you are doing a static site rather than SSR and feels exceedingly bulky.
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  hooks: {
    async "prerender:routes"(ctx) {
      const { pages } = await fetch("https://api.some-cms.com/pages").then(
        (res) => res.json(),
      );
      for (const page of pages) {
        ctx.routes.add(`/${page.name}`);
      }
    },
  },
});

https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/prerendering#prerenderroutes-nuxt-hook

Thank you very much for your effort. I remember .server pages lead to unexpected rendering as well. On the client-side they do not fetch the API, but, at least in my case, the styling is not properly applied to the child components of the page. Your explanation makes sense. I interpreted the docs differently. The problem when navigation is not making a fetch from the server (for example to request the payload) but making a fetch from the API which is accessible from the client. I will figure out a different solution for that.

The approach with the pretender:routes hook is not suitable in this case.

Ah, dang. Well, good luck! Out of curiosity, what kind of rendering issues did you have with .server pages?

As far as I can remember some CSS wasn't applied. But this was some months ago.
